# Best way to filter data on site

Tags: javascript, function, filtering

I write a small application which shows restaurants and pubs. I want to add a function to filter data by category. I get data in my script from external *.json file. There are only two categories - "bar" and "restaurant".

I would be very greatful if you can give me a hint about filtering in existing elements. After generation of cards with places you want to show only bars, so you click button "bars" and there are only bars on site, restaurants are hidden.

```
function updateData() {

    var results = document.getElementById("results");

    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        results.innerHTML += '<div class="result text-center">' +
            '<img class="rest-img img-thumbnail" width="236" height="236" src="img/img1.jpg">' +
            '<h2 class="rest-name">' + places[i].name + '</h2>' +
            '<p class="rest-category">' + places[i].category + '</p>' +
            '<p class="rest-address">' + places[i].address + '</p>' +
            '<i class="fa fa-beer" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="rest-beer-price">' + places[i].price + ' PLN</p>';
    }
}

function showBars() {
    //Code to filter bars
}

var warsaw = document.getElementById("warsaw");
warsaw.addEventListener("click", updateData);
```

Many thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Not related to your question, but please use `results.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ...your HTML...)` to add new elements using HTML markup. Using `results.innerHTML += ...` has many problems that you'll eventually encounter.

Comment: I'll keep it in my mind, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is with a `filter` function:

```
function filterByCategory(list, category) {
  return list.filter(function(item) {
    return (item.category === category);
  }); 
}
```

The `filter` command expects a return of `true` to keep things and false to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

Give the root of each item that needs to be filtered a class that represents their category. Then have the `results` element add or remove a class for each category that should be shown. Then it's just a matter of adding some CSS that only displays the categories of elements when the respective class exists on `results`.

Almost no JS needed with this approach. Updating the display is handled entirely by CSS. JS is only needed to toggle the class on `results`.

```js
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("results").classList.toggle("foo")
})
document.getElementById("bar").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("results").classList.toggle("bar")
})
```

```css
#results .item {
  display: none;
}

#results.foo .fooCat {
  display: block;
  color: green;
}
#results.bar .barCat {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button id=foo>TOGGLE FOO</button>
<button id=bar>TOGGLE BAR</button>

<div id=results>
<p class="item fooCat">FOO ITEM</p>
<p class="item fooCat">FOO ITEM</p>
<p class="item barCat">BAR ITEM</p>
<p class="item fooCat">FOO ITEM</p>
<p class="item barCat">BAR ITEM</p>
<p class="item barCat">BAR ITEM</p>
<p class="item fooCat">FOO ITEM</p>
</div>
```